# How to install mods in Minecraft 1.9.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

How can i install mods in dedicated Minecraft server, since Forge wont work with 1.9.2 at the moment 'cause there's no download on the official site and craftbukkit has dmca claim and also not available.

So how can i install mods for vanilla minecraft without Forge or Craftbukkit?

**Edit**

I tried rolling back Minecraft to 1.9 but i got the error **ERROR Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException** in the Forge server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you will have to wait for update patches to be made by the developers before you can have the a server work on the latest version. (Unless you want to make the patch yourself. :)
Also, I believe that CraftBukkit does not run mods... You could try Spigot, which receives frequent updates if you are looking to add Plugins, not Mods.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I will wait for Forge updates and try out Spigot. :)